# How to make a specific graph?

Tags: python, plot

Currently I am encountering a problem regarding a graph I would like to make. I do have a set of replicated results and a predefined acceptance range.

```
UL = 1.5 # Lower limit of the acceptance range
LL = 1.0 # Upper limit of the acceptance range
results = [1.1,1.13,1.26,1.05,1.37] # Sample results
```

I would like to make a graph that looks like this:

[image]

This means that the acceptance range is given by the error-bar and the results are separate dots. I have no clue how to do this, is there somebody who could give me some advise?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add a white margin around your figure. When I was using the new [dark mode](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/?cb=1), your image (and hence your question) appeared quite weird to me. It's much clearer with a white background or some white margin. Maybe [box plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-boxplot-demo-pyplot-py) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have solved the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import seaborn as sns

UL = 1.5 # Lower limit of the acceptance range
LL = 1.0 # Upper limit of the acceptance range
df = pd.DataFrame({'Results':['Sample']*10,'Data':[1.1,1.13,1.26,1.05,1.37,1.2,1.14,1.22,1.09,1.30]}) # Sample results

Acc_c= pd.DataFrame({'Results':['Sample','Sample'],'Limit':[UL,LL]})

plt.figure(0)
ax=sns.stripplot(x="Results", y='Data', data=df,size=10,jitter=0.000012)
sns.set_style("white")
sns.pointplot(x="Results", y="Limit", data=Acc_c, capsize=0.00007, join=False, scale = 0,color='black')
```